# Writing zeroes to file block does not work

Tags: c++, windows

So I'm trying to write a sequence of zeroes from a file offset until the end of the file, here is my code:

```
    HANDLE hFile = CreateFileA((LPCSTR)"hello.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    
    if(hFile < 0) return -1;

    DWORD   fileSize = GetFileSize(hFile, NULL);    

    DWORD   offset  = 0x13d4;

    DWORD   check   = NULL;
    DWORD   pos     = SetFilePointer(hFile, offset, 0, FILE_BEGIN);
    
    BYTE*   zeroes  = new BYTE[fileSize-offset];
    
    ZeroMemory((PVOID)zeroes, fileSize-offset);
    
    WriteFile(hFile, (PVOID)&zeroes, fileSize-offset, &check, NULL);
    
    printf("Wrote %d bytes at %x\n", check, pos);
    
    if(check < fileSize-offset)
    {
        printf("[+] An error occured while trying to patch the file.");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    CloseHandle(hFile);
```

Now I checked my fileSize is correct, the file offset (`pos`) is the same as `offset`, my file Handle is valid, the number of bytes written stored in `check` is equal to the the `zeroes` buffer length and the last error is 0. However, when I check my file in hex mode it did not add any zeroes at the end.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What if you try to add something after the zeroes? Are they not written, or are they just invisible?

Comment: @IWonderWhatThisAPIDoes They are not written at all, the data stays the same after the offset and it does not contain any zeroes.

Comment: [`FSCTL_SET_ZERO_DATA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winioctl/ni-winioctl-fsctl_set_zero_data) exist for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
    WriteFile(hFile, (PVOID)&zeroes, fileSize-offset, &check, NULL);
```

is wrong. You are writing data in the pointer variable `zeroes` itself, not what is pointed at by the variable. Typically the pointer has only 4 or 8 bytes, so it may cause out-of-range access if the file is large enough.

Remove `&` before `zeros` to have it write contents of the buffer pointed at by `zeroes`.

```
    WriteFile(hFile, (PVOID)zeroes, fileSize-offset, &check, NULL);
```